# How to see the history log Message of Mesos when Master or Slave restart

Tags: mesos

I'm developing a Web App, I need to get the logs of mesos ,  Normally, I can get that with 
Url: http://host:5051/files/read.json?

but when the Master or Slave restart ,  I could not get the logs..
Please tell me how could I  get that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All logs are stored in the log directory you specify via a `--log_dir` flag. I'm not sure you can access logs from previous runs via WebUI, but you can definitely ssh into the specific machine.

Comment: have you erver  used  org.apache.mesos.Log  ?  How to use it  ? ,, the api is too little about it ,

Comment: `org.apache.mesos.Log` is JAVA binding to the replicated log implementation. I don't think this is what your question is about.

Comment: what i want to do  is  that  use the replicated log to copy the logs on salves to the Application server ，In order to visit the log  of  task by some parameters on my webUI . is that  viable ？

Comment: I don't think so. Replicated log has a different goal, see here: http://mesos.apache.org/blog/mesos-0-17-0-released-featuring-autorecovery/